# sails connect to postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, sails.js

my adapter looks like this
**config/connections.js**

```
  herokuPG: {
    adapter: 'sails-postgresql',
    url: 'process.env.DATABASE_URL',
    pool: false,
    ssl: false
  }
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "<omitted>",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "a Sails application",
  "keywords": [],
  "dependencies": {
    "sails": "~0.10.0-rc5",
    "sails-disk": "~0.10.0",
    "rc": "~0.3.3",
    "include-all": "~0.1.3",
    "ejs": "~0.8.4",
    "grunt": "0.4.2",
    "grunt-sync": "~0.0.4",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-sails-linker": "~0.9.5",
    "grunt-contrib-jst": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "~0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.10.1",
    "sails-postgresql": "^0.10.0-rc4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "debug": "node debug app.js"
  },
  "main": "app.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "<ommited>"
  },
  "author": "harrymoreno",
  "license": ""
}
```

**error**

```
2014-06-25T09:20:20.696476+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 78d27cf by morenoh149@gmail.com
2014-06-25T09:20:20.696476+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v8 created by morenoh149@gmail.com
2014-06-25T09:20:25.206447+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2014-06-25T09:20:28.317530+00:00 app[web.1]: Error creating a connection to Postgresql: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
2014-06-25T09:20:28.319161+00:00 app[web.1]: error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
2014-06-25T09:20:28.321347+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19) Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
2014-06-25T09:20:28.319165+00:00 app[web.1]:     at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
2014-06-25T09:20:28.319168+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19) Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
2014-06-25T09:20:28.321340+00:00 app[web.1]: error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
2014-06-25T09:20:28.321344+00:00 app[web.1]:     at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
2014-06-25T09:20:28.318456+00:00 app[web.1]: error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
2014-06-25T09:20:29.597434+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-06-25T09:20:29.598968+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-06-25T09:20:29.587153+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2014-06-25T09:20:36.247496+00:00 app[web.1]: error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
2014-06-25T09:20:36.248153+00:00 app[web.1]: error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
2014-06-25T09:20:36.250261+00:00 app[web.1]:     at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
2014-06-25T09:20:36.250263+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19) Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
2014-06-25T09:20:36.243584+00:00 app[web.1]: Error creating a connection to Postgresql: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
2014-06-25T09:20:36.250259+00:00 app[web.1]: error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
2014-06-25T09:20:36.248156+00:00 app[web.1]:     at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
2014-06-25T09:20:36.248158+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19) Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
2014-06-25T09:20:33.439829+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2014-06-25T09:20:37.580073+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2014-06-25T09:20:38.452081+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=txtbinge-landing.herokuapp.com request_id=b3bee9ff-826d-46e7-9537-38e923740ba1 fwd="173.228.123.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-25T09:20:38.804141+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=txtbinge-landing.herokuapp.com request_id=e24d1a2c-28d9-4155-b79c-32c05649e43a fwd="173.228.123.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-25T09:20:37.591982+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I'm not using the `pg` module as per the [heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#using-a-postgresql-database) I'm using the 0.10.x version of the [sails postgresql adapter](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-postgresql)

Comment: Ben's answer below is correct, but also the `url` shouldn't be in quotes since it's referring to an environment var.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After looking at the Heroku docs I found [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#external-connections-ingress).

> All connections require SSL: sslmode=require.

You need to set **ssl** to **true**.

```
herokuPG: {
  adapter: 'sails-postgresql',
  url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  pool: false,
  ssl: true
}
```